# How can I open .TC extensions in Truecrypt by default and mount automatically?

Tags: automount, default-programs, file-format, truecrypt

I have Truecrypt installed on my Ubuntu 64 bit machine and I have many Truecrypt partitions that I share with friends.

Its not always convenient to:

```
Open truecrypt > browse to the file and then mount.
```

Is there a way of configuring so that when I double click the .tc file it directly opens in Truecrypt and accepts the root and volume password and mounts it automatically?